# Error using gRPC with Tensorflow Serving Docker container on EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to send a gRPC request to a TF serving Docker container running on an AWS EC2 instance. Running the container locally works fine, but sending the request to the ec2 instance gives the error:

```
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1579191873.586895058","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3941,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1579191873.586883203","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":393,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

I start the container with

```
sudo docker run -p 8500:8500 -p 8501:8501 --mount type=bind,source=/home/ubuntu/tf_serving/models/zipnet,target=/models/zipnet -e MODEL_NAME=zipnet -t tensorflow/serving:latest --enable_batching &
```

and the code to generate the request looks like this

```
from tensorflow_serving.apis import predict_pb2, prediction_service_pb2_grpc
import grpc

def prepare_grpc_request(model, sig, data):
    request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
    request.model_spec.name = model
    request.model_spec.signature_name = sig
    request.inputs['input_img'].CopyFrom(tf.make_tensor_proto(data, dtype=None))
    return request

model_name = 'zipnet'
signature_name = 'serving_default'

stub = prediction_service_pb2_grpc.PredictionServiceStub(grpc.insecure_channel('<ipv4 public ip>:8500'))

request = prepare_grpc_request(model_name, signature_name, batch)

result = stub.Predict(request, 120.0)
```

This works with `localhost` and running the container locally. The container should be listening for gRPC requests on port 8500 which is open. Notably, I'm able to make REST requests to the container with no problems on port 8501.

I've also tried using `grpc.secure_channel()` with `credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()` to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your container behind a load balancer? gRPC operates using HTTP/2 and I wouldn't be surprised if [an AWS load balancer downgraded to HTTP/1.1 for the connection from the balancer to the backend.](https://rokt.com/engineering_blog/learnings-grpc-aws/)